# GridView with responsive FooTable plugin breaks when clicked on edit link

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, footable

I am trying to make gridview responsive using footable plugin. On page load in mobile view the page gets loaded properly hiding the columns in plus sign but when clicked on edit link of particular row the page gets loaded but plus sign of footable gets disabled. here is my code:

MasterPage.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Surveillance.master.cs" Inherits="Surviellance_Surveillance" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Style/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/0.1.0/css/footable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">

    <form id="frm" runat="server">
        <header>
        </header>
        <div class="container-fluid" id="body">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BodyContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <div id="blankDiv" class="overlay">
                <div class="messagealert " id="alert_container">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="panel-footer white">
            <div class="row">
            </div>
        </footer>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-footable/0.1.0/js/footable.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
         $('.AspGridview').footable({
             breakpoints: {
                phone: 480,
                tablet: 1024
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

ChildPage.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Surviellance/Surveillance.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GSMFlagMaster.aspx.cs" Inherits="Surviellance_GSMMaker" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContentPlaceHolder" runat="Server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <div class="panel-body">
            <fieldset>
                <legend class="legend">

                </legend>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body table-responsive">

                        <div class="table table-borderless">
                           <asp:GridView ID="grdGMasterDetails" runat="server"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="7"
                                CssClass="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover AspGridview footable"
                                OnPageIndexChanging="grdGMasterDetails_PageIndexChanging"
                                OnRowDataBound="grdGMasterDetails_RowDataBound"
                                OnSorting="grdGMasterDetails_Sorting">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="G_FLAG_CODE" SortExpression="G_FLAG_CODE" HeaderText="Flag Code"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="G_FLAG_DESCRIPTION" SortExpression="G_FLAG_DESCRIPTION" HeaderText="Flag Description"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Trade to Trade Flag" SortExpression="TRADE_TO_TRADE_FLAG">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkTtoT" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ASD_PER" SortExpression="ASD_PER" HeaderText="ASD"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Weekly Trading" SortExpression="WEEK_TRADING_ALLOWED">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkWeek" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Monthly Trading" SortExpression="MONTH_TRADING_ALLOWED">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkMonth" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="EFFECTIVE_FROM" SortExpression="EFFECTIVE_FROM" HeaderText="Effective From" DataFormatString="{0:d}"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="EFFECTIVE_TO" SortExpression="EFFECTIVE_TO" HeaderText="Effective To" DataFormatString="{0:d}"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="STATUS" SortExpression="STATUS" HeaderText="Status"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ENTRY_BY" SortExpression="ENTRY_BY" HeaderText="Entry By"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ENTRY_DATE" SortExpression="ENTRY_DATE" HeaderText="Entry Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkButton" runat="server" CommandName="CMDEdit" CausesValidation="false" Font-Underline="true" OnClick="LnkButton_Click">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#c0e6fa" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0089d0" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#0089d0" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

childpage.aspx.cs

```
//binding data to gridview
protected DataTable BindGrid()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConn"].ToString()))
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM DBO.WEB_SURV_G_FLAG_MASTER ORDER BY [G_FLAG_CODE]";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = "G_FLAG_CODE ASC";
        grdGMasterDetails.DataSource = dt;
        grdGMasterDetails.DataBind();
        grdGMasterDetails.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

        grdGMasterDetails.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
        grdGMasterDetails.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Attributes["data-class"] = "expand";
        grdGMasterDetails.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
        grdGMasterDetails.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
        grdGMasterDetails.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
        grdGMasterDetails.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
        grdGMasterDetails.HeaderRow.Cells[6].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
        grdGMasterDetails.HeaderRow.Cells[7].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
        grdGMasterDetails.HeaderRow.Cells[8].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
        grdGMasterDetails.HeaderRow.Cells[9].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
        grdGMasterDetails.HeaderRow.Cells[10].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
        grdGMasterDetails.HeaderRow.Cells[11].Attributes["data-hide"] = "phone";
        int count = grdGMasterDetails.Rows.Count;
        lblRecordsCount.Text = count.ToString();
        con.Close();
        return dt;            
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you call `$('.AspGridview').footable` after the UpdatePanel refresh.

Comment: @VDWWD footable is called in master page.

Comment: There is no master/child page as far as html/javascript is concerned.

Comment: then how could i know if it is called after updatepanel refresh or not

Answer (score 0):

Load Footable under the pageLoad function like

```
function pageLoad()
{
    $(".table").footable();
}
```